# Error calling ASP.net webservice with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, webforms

I'm attempting to call an ASP webservice using jQuery with a complex object as an input.

Here is my jQuery fn:

```
    request: function (url, method, data) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: json,
            error: ErrorHelpers.printErrorToConsole,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false
        });
    }
```

the json being passed in looks like this:

```
{
    "search": {
        "WarehouseId": "",
        "AuctionId": "",
        "Barcode": "",
        "Name": "",
        "CategoryId": "",
        "Description": "",
        "ManufacturerId": "",
        "StatusId": "",
        "StatusOperator": "",
        "HasPhoto": "",
        "DateReceived": "",
        "SellerAdministrativeArea": "",
        "SellerId": "",
        "IsApproved": "",
        "Keyword": "",
        "SortBy": "",
        "RowStart": "",
        "RowLimit": "10"
    }
}
```

and my web method definition is as follows:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public List<ClientInventory> GetInventory(string search)
    { //code
    }
```

Does anyone know why it's erroring out? Here is the response I get:

> {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
>   \u0027search\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: How are you building the URL string/parameter?

Comment: it's hardcoded. /api/blah.asmx/GetInventory

Comment: it's expecting a string, you're passing an object of search? What should your code do with all that data?

Comment: Changing the param to object makes no difference either.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class...

```
public class Search
{
    public string WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public string AuctionId { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public string StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusOperator { get; set; }
    public string HasPhoto { get; set; }
    public string DateReceived { get; set; }
    public string SellerAdministrativeArea { get; set; }
    public string SellerId { get; set; }
    public string IsApproved { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public string RowStart { get; set; }
    public string RowLimit { get; set; }
}
```

and modify your method like this...

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public List<ClientInventory> GetInventory(Search search)
    { //code
    }
```

Also, check the method you are using here...

```
type: method,
```

It suggests in the error that you're using a `Post`?

Comment: I attempted exactly that (before posting the question), but no luck. :/

Comment: It says you're using a POST? but you have UseHTTPGet

Comment: dangit I'm an idiot. I copied the error message from the wrong tab. I've edited the question with the correct one; my apologies and thanks for your help/time!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you shouldn't use `JSON.stringify()` when you're sending GET requests. Changing the app to send/receive POST requests solved the problem.

The method signature now looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    //[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public List<ClientInventory> GetInventory(Search search)
    {}
```

and the `request` fn in the js is now passing the method as a "POST".

Comment: No, the error was unrelated to your suggestion. The problem was using `JSON.stringify()` when sending the params for a post request. I think your suggestion was to make sure I wasn't accidentally sending a post when I should've been sending a get.

Comment: The suggestion was to check you're using the correct type and replace `string` with the `search` class I provided?  You still need to use `JSON.stringify()` - or are you now passing as string?

Comment: So, did you end up using a `string` or the `Search` class?